# Invalid Expression on else if and else statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, syntax-error, break

There's an error that says invalid expression on 'else if' and 'else'

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Random numberGenerator = new Random ();

            int num01 = numberGenerator.Next (1,11);
            int num02 = numberGenerator.Next (1,11);
            int realAnswer = num01 * num02 ;

            Console.WriteLine ("What is " + num01 + " multiplied by " + num02 + "?");

            int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            if (userAnswer == realAnswer) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Good");
            } else if (userAnswer - realAnswer >= 1 && userAnswer - realAnswer <= 3) {

                int greater = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

                switch (greater) {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine ("little too high");
                break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine ("little too much");
                    break;

                } else if (realAnswer-userAnswer  >= 1 && realAnswer-userAnswer  <=3) {

                    int less = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

                    switch (less) {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine ("little too low");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine ("go higher!");
                        break;

                    } else {

                        Console.WriteLine ("you just suck");

                    }

                    Console.ReadKey ();

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having, and that will be useful to future readers here when trying to solve their problem. *Please help I'm getting errors* provides no information about the problem. It's clear you're asking for help, or you wouldn't be posting here, and *I'm getting errors* will have no value in a search result later. Thanks.

Comment: thanks ken, i will for next time

Comment: Not next time. Please [edit] *now* to do so, so that this question will have future value here.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a compiler, unclear what you are asking !

Comment: ok, you've missed curly bracket after "switch (greater)" statement. Current code looks like "switch (greater) {...} else if".

Answer (score 3):

You are missing closing curly braces (`}`) after both switches:

```
if (userAnswer == realAnswer) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Good");
} else if (userAnswer - realAnswer >= 1 && userAnswer - realAnswer <= 3) {

    int greater = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

    switch (greater) {
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine ("little too high");
    break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine ("little too much");
        break;

    } 
} // Was missing in the OP
else if (realAnswer-userAnswer  >= 1 && realAnswer-userAnswer  <=3) {

        int less = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

        switch (less) {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine ("little too low");
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine ("go higher!");
            break;

        } 
} // Was also missing
else {
    Console.WriteLine ("you just suck");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget Brace at the end of switchs: Be careful

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random numberGenerator = new Random ();

            int num01 = numberGenerator.Next (1,11);
            int num02 = numberGenerator.Next (1,11);
            int realAnswer = num01 * num02 ;

            Console.WriteLine ("What is " + num01 + " multiplied by " + num02 + "?");

            int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            if (userAnswer == realAnswer) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Good");
            } else if (userAnswer - realAnswer >= 1 && userAnswer - realAnswer <= 3) {

                int greater = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

                switch (greater) {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine ("little too high");
                break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine ("little too much");
                    break;
                }

                } else if ((realAnswer-userAnswer  >= 1) && (realAnswer-userAnswer  <=3)) {

                    int less = numberGenerator.Next (1, 3);

                    switch (less) {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine ("little too low");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine ("go higher!");
                        break;
                    }
            } else {

                        Console.WriteLine ("you just suck");

                    }

                    Console.ReadKey ();

                    }
```